# Histogram in matplotlib not binning correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a histogram from some bootstrapped data, but my histogram isn't binning properly.  Rather than showing frequencies, it just plots every single point as its own bin.

Each point is its own color, so I'm not sure if it's taking each entry as its own series.

Here's my code:

```
 import pip
import xlrd as xlrd
import numpy as np
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


exams212 = pd.read_excel('212bare.xlsx')
df = DataFrame(exams212)

mc =df.query('Gender == "M" and Treatment == "C"')
mt =df.query('Gender == "M" and Treatment == "T"')
fc =df.query('Gender == "F" and Treatment == "C"')
ft=df.query('Gender == "F" and Treatment == "T"')


#MC averages
mcave = []
for x in range(10):

    rows = mc.sample(n=381, replace=True)
    mcavg=rows.mean()

    mcave.append(mcavg)

print(mcave)

mcplot=plt.hist(mcave,bins=5)
plt.show(mcplot)
```

I'll eventually do this for way larger numbers, but I've been playing with ten for now just to troubleshoot, trying to force 5 bins to see if I can make it do what I want.

The return on my print comes out as I'd expect:

```
[P212 EX1    0.73931
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.72205
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.71315
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.717682
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.730556
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.730562
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.726436
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.736711
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.749921
dtype: float64, P212 EX1    0.74974
dtype: float64]
```

but the plot I get looks like this, with 10 bins, one for each data point: 
[histogram not binned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v4Qp.png)

Is there something silly I'm missing?  I've been trying to figure this out and can't find anything.  Thank you!

Comment: It seems `hist` is treating `mcave` as 10 different datasets, so you effectively have 10 histograms each with only one data point. What data type are the elements of `mcave`? It doesn't seem to be a list of numeric data--such as a list of ints.

Comment: See [mcve] and provide one for further help.